# Get the value of REDIRECT using WITH in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

we are trying to get the value sent with the redirect method in blade template in laravel.

Here is how my `return` statement looks like:

```
public function movetotrash($id){

    $page = Pages::where('id', $id) -> first();
    $page -> active = 0;
    //$page -> save();
    //return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('trash','Page Moved To Trash');
    return redirect('pages')->with('trash','Page Moved To Trash');
}
```

Now once its redirect to `pages` it creates are URL like this http://localhost:8888/laravelCRM/public/pages.

Then i want to print the message to user that "Page is moved to trash" with $trash variable. For which i used this :

```
@if(isset($trash) ))
                       <div class="alert alert-error">
                          {{ $trash }}<br><br>
                       </div>
                    @endif
```

What should i do to print the value?

Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 1):

The with method flashes data to the session which is only accessible in the next request.
So you can retrieve it from the session like this:

```
@if(session()->has('trash'))
    <div class="alert alert-error">
        {{ session()->get('trash') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but its not working :(. Do i need to add any session class at the controller page?

Comment: Can you add your `pages` route from `routes.php` and the controller code that this route calls to your question?

Comment: Sorry but i didnt call this on routes.php, i call this inside a controller and with in a function.

Comment: What does your app do when it redirects to `pages` when you do `return redirect('pages')`? This `pages` url is in the routes.php or not?

Comment: Yes it redirects to a resource route. And that resource route is `index()` and my URL becomes http://localhost:8888/laravelCRM/public/pages which shows a view.

Comment: Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');

Comment: //inside PageController

`public function index()
    {
     //$pages= Pages::all();

        $pages=Pages::where('active', 1)->get();
       
        return view('pages.pages')->with('pages',$pages);
    }`

Comment: That is really weird. Are you sure sessions are working? What session driver are you using? Try to make a route that sets something in the session and a route that retrieves that value again.

Comment: Yes sessions are working. I have to use query string for now to make it work. I use `return redirect('pages?trashed=true');` and use the regular $_GET method to check if trashed is true.

Answer (score 0):

In redirect with value pass as session flash,so you need to check value like that

```
@if(session()->has('trash'))
```

then you can show like this

```
{{ session('trash') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data from controller like this,
You have to assign the message into variable

```
$trash = Page Moved To Trash';
return redirect('pages')->with('trash');
```

and then in view,
use like this.

```
@if(session($trash) ))
                       <div class="alert alert-error">
                          {{ session($trash) }}<br><br>
                       </div>
                    @endif
```

The data will store in session and we can use it on redirect page

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Yes this is also one way. but right now i used `return redirect('pages?trashed=true');` query string and then $_GET method to check if its trashed or not.